# Searching a file in FileZilla

Tags: search, filezilla

How do I find a file by filename in a remote connection in FileZilla 3.6.0.2? I couldn't find a built-in search function so I was wondering wether there are any plugins that could do that.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Ubuntu specific question, anyway on a clean install of the newest Filezilla do it exist a button on the toolbar to do a recursive remote search after files. Also exist a record to do the same in the menubar item Server. The shortcut is also F3.